# Роль авторизированного пользователя

Tags: yii2

Использую RBAC. Вопрос такой возник: нужна ли отдельная роль типа `user` для каждого зарегистрированного юзера? Ну раньше я делал так:

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
$userRole = $auth->createRole('user');
$userRole->description = 'Пользователь';
$auth->add($userRole);
```

И для каждого юзера в `afterSave` (когда `insert`) присваивал эту роль. Но мне кажется что возможно это излишне? Ведь любой юзер - уже как-бы юзер, зачем нужна эта роль? Тем более что есть псевдороль `@` обозначающая любого авторизированного юзера. Вот только можно ли этой роли присваивать какие-то разрешения? Скажем у меня есть правило дающее возможность юзеру редактировать свои статьи и мне тогда надо сделать что-то вроде:

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
$userRole = $auth->getRole('@');
$updateOwnArticlePermission = $auth->getPermission('updateOwnArticle');
$auth->addChild($userRole, $updateOwnArticlePermission);
```

Так не выходит - `$auth->getRole('@')` возвращает `null`.

Comment: Если надо позволить редактировать свои статьи, то в любом случае придется проверять кому принадлежит статья, это и будет разрешением. Гость не может редактировать никакую статью.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что Вы смешиваете две разные вещи

> Yii предоставляет два метода авторизации: фильтры контроля доступа (ACF) и контроль доступа на основе ролей (RBAC).

В ACF через параметр rules Вы фильтруете пользователей при помощи специальных ролей "?" и "@".
В RBAC этого параметра и таких ролей нет.

Подробней [тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/security-authorization.md)

https://elisdn.ru/blog/87/seo-service-on-yii2-adding-rbac

https://elisdn.ru/blog/79/authentication-and-rbac-on-yii2

Comment: Но ведь в filter я могу писать не только `?` и `@`, но и роли! И это работает. Ладно, тогда как правильно реализовать то о чем я говорю? Некая дефолтная роль для всех пользователей? Ну просто даже как-то нерационально хранить данные в `auth_assignment` о том что каждому юзеру присваевается роль `user` - это очевидно и так.

Comment: Вы можете создать сколько угодно ролей. Например: guest, user, auth_user, moderator и так далее. Или проверяйте через Yii::$app->user->isGuest. При помощи rbac Вы присваиваете разные роли и каждой роли свои возможности. Гость только читать, user читать, добавлять, редактировать свои тексты, модератор + ко всему редактировать ещё и тексты других пользователей... Почитайте по ссылке, я думаю Вы не до конца поняли rbac

Comment: добавил пару полезнейших ссылок

Comment: Кажется я понял - то о чем я спрашивал решается параметром defaultRoles в конфиге.

Comment: Вообще я и правда плохо понимаю в чем преимущество RBAC перед тем чтобы просто написать одно поле в модели юзера - `role` и сравнивать где надо... Просто с RBAC выходит надо на каждый чих создавать правила, что тоже не особо удобно.

Comment: Вы создаёте правила один раз, изначально продумав какая роль для чего нужна. И потом назначаете эти роли. Читайте и смотрите по ссылкам. Там очень толково всё разъясняется.

Comment: Естественно, сначала назначается какая-то роль по умолчанию.